# Highslide conflicting with slimScroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, conflict

I'm working on a site that is using Highslide JS to create a slideshow window of larger product images when an image on the product page is clicked. I'm also using Piotr Rochala's fine jQuery plugin, slimScroll, as an alternative to ugly browser default scrollers on the same page.

The problem occurs when a product image is clicked, creating a new .highslide-controls div behind the slideshow that should only be in the top of the slideshow window. The div gets appended with each click, which I believe I've narrowed down to a conflict with the slimScroll script.

See: http://www.thelifeguardstore.com/newproductcart/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=7409

I've attempted using jQuery's noConflict(), changing up the orders of when scripts are called, and looking at each script's JS code, but can't find exactly what's causing the problem. Although I have a feeling it's probably right in front of me, laughing maniacally.

Any help or clues as to what may be causing the issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately could not find a solution. Wound up just using default scroll bars because we're trying to push the new site design live as soon as we can and really didn't want something that trivial holding us back. I used webkit specific scroll bar styles though to achieve what I wanted so at least they'll look cool in Chrome/Safari which comprise around 41% of our users.